# How can I put the desired data from csv right into the variable?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have the .csv data file to parse and using java language for this purpose.
Therefore, I understand how can I use data and put it to the variable working, for example, with two dimensional arrays:

```
//working with 2-dimensial Arrays
int[][] values = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
                   {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
                   {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 
                   {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
                   {21, 22, 23, 24, 25} };
                  
//output of the 1st column, 1st line array value 
System.out.println(values[0][0]);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("alex", "brian", "charles", "dough"));

    String firstName = list.get(0);         
    String secondName = list.get(1); 
    
    System.out.println(firstName);
```

But I need to read the .csv file first and then make the multidimensional array. After this I need to pick up some data and put it into the variables.
I read csv without any specifical libraries, only standard like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName= "datatry.csv";
        File file= new File(fileName);

      
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
   
        Scanner inputStream;
//this scanner of csv doesn't work without try-catch pair
        try{
            //read the csv file 
            inputStream = new Scanner(file);

            while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                String line= inputStream.next();
                String[] values = line.split(";");
                // this adds the currently parsed line to the 2-dimensional string array
                lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }
//System.out.println(value);

            inputStream.close();
        }
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      //  String newst = lines.get(1);
//System.out.println(newst);
        // the following code lets you iterate through the 2-dimensional array
        int lineNo = 1;
        for(List<String> line: lines) {
            int columnNo = 1;
            for (String value: line) {
                System.out.println("Line " + lineNo + " Column " + columnNo + ": " + value);
                columnNo++;
            }
            lineNo++;
        }
        }}
```

I guess I need to use Object ?

How can I put the value of third column and fifth line of the .csv file into the integer variable?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Java.  But I do know how to read every line, and every column of a csv file in powershell, and stuff the value into a variable with the same name as the column header, except with a dollar sign prefix.  You might be able to use a similar technique.  I wrote a simple csv template engine in powershell.  You can see it at www.github.com/dcressey/expand-csv

Comment: Thanks, @WalterMitty for you support, but I write on Java. And going to get the solution on this programming language

Comment: Sure thing.  I don't know how easily the technique ports from powershell to java.  Sorry.

Comment: @WalterMitty I'll analyse your github solution , may be will understand the technique which will be useful in my task. Anyway, I appreciate your help

Comment: I think you'll find that my solution is heavily dependent on tools made available in the powershell environment.  I have no ide of the extent to which parallel tools exist in Java libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

1. set targetRoNumber and targetColNumber
2. Create 2 for-loops to track the indexes. The first loop is for the row, second loop is for the column.
3. Create if condition to match the target row and column number

```
        String csvFilePath = "D:\\Project\\sample.csv";

        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(csvFilePath);
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
            int targetRowNumber=5;
            int targetColNumber=3;
            //Integer extractedNumber=null;
            for(int row=0;row<lines.size();row++) {
                String line = lines.get(row);
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                
                for(int col=0;col<fields.length;col++) {
                    if(row==targetRowNumber && col==targetColNumber) {
                        int extractedNumber = Integer.parseInt(fields[col]);
                        System.out.println(extractedNumber);
                    }
                }   
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

or if you dont want loops, just go directly to the index

```
 String csvFilePath = "D:\\Project\\sample.csv";
        int targetRowNumber = 5;
        int targetColNumber = 3;

        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(csvFilePath));

            if (targetRowNumber < lines.size()) {
                String[] fields = lines.get(targetRowNumber).split(",");

                if (targetColNumber < fields.length) {
                    int extractedNumber = Integer.parseInt(fields[targetColNumber]);
                    System.out.println(extractedNumber);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I used 'java.nio', a standard java package

Comment: your solution has too many errors and doesn't compile

Comment: @Programmer1988 it works on my end. I used java 8. Just import the stuffs needed

Comment: you gave non-working solution and it is against the platform rules. you must correct it fist